# Error Propagation and CV?

Tags: standard-deviation, error-propagation, coefficient-of-variation

I would like to know if someone can help me with basic statistical questions, please.
I read in many documents on the internet that if I want to calculate the mean of two values, where each value has a standard deviation, I should always propagate the error.
For example:
On day 1 I had two measurements for a replicate 1 of an experiment, therefore my final result for replicate 1 is composed of a mean and standard deviation.
On day 2 I perform the same experiment, having at the end another mean and standard deviation.
Now I want to analyze mean, SD and CV (%) between replicates. Thus, I calculate the mean between the two means and the standard deviation is calculated considering the error propagation.
My question is: To calculate the CV between the two replicates, should I consider the SD with error propagation?
If you have any material that explains this, I would appreciate it very much, since I did not find much on the internet and some books regarding CV calculation when error propagation is used to calculate SD.